# Getting rectangle coordinates created in custom QgsMapTool Class of PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am developing a QGIS (QGIS 3.6) dockwidget plugin where the user creates a rectangle (boundingbox) on the canvas and the plugin sends the rectangles coordinates attached to a HTTP request to my FME Server.

There is the main class `SmallworldDataExtractorDockWidget` and another class [`RectangleMapTool`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/gui/RectangleMapTool.py). In `SmallworldDataExtractorDockWidget` the general plugin functionalities are defined, in `RectangleMapTool` I create a custom QgsMapTool for creating the boundingbox in the canvas.

The creation of the boundingbox itself works and the `RectangleMapTool` can print the rectangle extent.

Now I am struggling in accessing the extent in the main class `SmallworldDataExtractorDockWidget`, where I want to associate the extent to variables and display the extent coordinates in input fields.

[image: Plugin UI]

What I have tried:

**First try:** In class `RectangleMaptool`:

```
def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.isEmittingPoint = False
        r = self.rectangle()
        if r is not None:
            print("Rectangle:", r.xMinimum(), r.yMinimum(), r.xMaximum(), r.yMaximum())
            SmallworldDataExtractorDockWidget().minx_input.setText(r.xMinimum())
```

Error: RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted

**Second try:** In class `RectangleMaptool`:

```
def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
    self.isEmittingPoint = False
    r = self.rectangle()
    if r is not None:
        print("Rectangle:", r.xMinimum(), r.yMinimum(), r.xMaximum(), r.yMaximum())
        self.result = r
```

and in class `SmallworldDataExtractorDockWidget`

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(SmallworldDataExtractorDockWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        #some code
        #some code
        #some code
        self.maptool = RectangleMapTool(iface.mapCanvas())
        self.maptool.canvasClicked.connect(self.temp_box)


def temp_box(self, r):
        print(self.maptool.result)
```

Without any output...